# GCP-Django-IP Address based error: write EPROTO error:100000f7 OPENSSL_internal

Tags: python, django, ssl, google-cloud-platform, postman

This is among the strangest issues I have seen.

When I make a postman GET api call to [this url](https://conferencecaptioning.uk.r.appspot.com/getAllRoomInfo/) in the US, I do not have any problems, it gives me the JSON I need. However, when I make the same API call in Canada (even using the same computer), it gives the following error:

```
Error: write EPROTO error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242:
```

You don't need Postman, you can also just navigate to the url to see the response.

The API is hosted on GCP (Google Cloud Platform) and uses the Python Django framework. There's no IP Address restrictions that I setup personally

I have gone through several responses with this error, but none have any solution that worked, and I'm not sure what to look for now

### UPDATES:

As requested I did two curl commands and here's the responses

```
curl -v -L https://conferencecaptioning.uk.r.appspot.com/getAllRoomInfo/
*   Trying 18.204.152.241:443...
* Connected to conferencecaptioning.uk.r.appspot.com (18.204.152.241) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* LibreSSL/3.3.6: error:1404B42E:SSL routines:ST_CONNECT:tlsv1 alert protocol version
* Closing connection 0
```

```
% curl -v -L http://conferencecaptioning.uk.r.appspot.com:443/getAllRoomInfo/
*   Trying 18.204.152.241:443...
* Connected to conferencecaptioning.uk.r.appspot.com (18.204.152.241) port 443 (#0)
> GET /getAllRoomInfo/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: conferencecaptioning.uk.r.appspot.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.84.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Screenshot of response when using http instead of https
[image: Postman screenshot]
Screenshot of response when using http & port 443
[image: 2nd postman picture]

Comment: Are you behind a proxy when in Canada? If you change `https` to `http` in the URL, does it work when in Canada?

Comment: Post the output from this command in your question: `curl -v -L https://conferencecaptioning.uk.r.appspot.com/getAllRoomInfo/` when in Canada.

Comment: Thank you for the response @JohnHanley
Will be back on my computer in 30 minutes, and will try that.

Comment: @JohnHanley hey I uploaded the curl command response in the question. Also there is no proxy that is setup on this connection that I am connected with. I tried using http instead as well, but that gave me a strange response that I shared in the question as well

Comment: The curl output tells me that the server is listening on port 443 but is supporting HTTP and not HTTPS. To prove that use this command: `curl -v -L http://conferencecaptioning.uk.r.appspot.com:443/getAllRoomInfo/`

Comment: @JohnHanley it took me a while to get back here. But I tried that curl command and shared the output in the question update

Comment: Have you verified the DNS settings as mentioned by @steffen-ullrich

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a DNS problem:

> The API is hosted on GCP (Google Cloud Platform) and uses the Python Django framework. There's no IP Address restrictions that I setup personally
> ...
> `* Connected to conferencecaptioning.uk.r.appspot.com (18.204.152.241) port 443 (#0)`

18.204.152.241 is not on GCP, it is on AWS.

Whereas from here it shows:
`* Connected to conferencecaptioning.uk.r.appspot.com (142.250.185.84) port 443 (#0)`

Where 142.250.185.84 is on GCP.

My guess is that the domain was moved from GCP to DNS. Since there is lots of caching going on with DNS such DNS propagation takes some time in which some already see the new addresses while others still use the old ones - leading to errors when accessing the system.

Comment: Thank you for the response! @SteffanUllrich how do I check these DNS settings? I was just using the basic url they provided

Comment: @Saamer: this depends on what exactly you want to check and on what system you are on. If you want to know which IP for a domain are seen by others use [DNS propagation checkers](https://www.google.com/search?q=check+dns+propagation). If you want to know what IP address is seen from a specific system use tools like nslookup or dig (depends on OS).